# Is there a way to deliberately return a null value with an Elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch, go, elasticsearch-plugin

I have to return an elasticsearch query in my code (Golang using olivere's elastic v.5 library) and if a particular condition occurs, I want to be able to pass in a query that will take minimal time and always return null. Is there a standard way to do this? I tried using a Term query with empty strings as parameters:

```
elastic.NewTermQuery("", "")
```

But this doesn't seem to be a valid query. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Firstly, kudos for your nick. Is there a reason to execute a pointless query when you are not supposed to? Smells a bit of bad design upfront...

Comment: The method return type contains an elastic query (among other things). It's an open source project so I have to work with/around the existing design

Answer (score 0):

If by "always return null" you mean match nothing:

```
{
    "bool": {
        "must_not": {
            "match_all": {}
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure match_all is implemented very efficiently.